# Global styles for angular project

Tags: angular, sass, colors

I have a project with colors.scss file. I want to import that as global style.

I used `@import 'src/app/core/styles/colors.scss'` in styles.scss file or included this path in angular.json:

```
"styles": [
   "src/app/core/styles/colors.scss"
   "src/styles.scss"
],
```

Also i set my colors in styles.scss:

```
$white:#ffffff;


$yellow-0:#fefdea;
$yellow-1:#FCF9BE;//FFEBD6
$yellow-2:#ebe79c;

$blue-0:#E8F3D6;
$blue-0-5:#d6e8f3;
$blue-1-5:#a4dbf7;
$blue-1:#003D5B;
$blue-2:#022d43;
$light-blue-1:#0a5e87;
$light-blue-2:#31b4ce;

$gray-1:#373F51;
$gray-2:#2b313e;

$green-1:#8BB174;
$green-2:#6a8c55;

$pink-1:#DB7F8E;
$pink-2:#c07380;

$red-0:#cd2e43;
$red-1:#D1495B;
$red-2:#ab3444;
$red-3:#80222e;

//$red-1:#FFB085;

$update-color-1:#DB7F8E;
$update-color-2:#bd717d;

$google-1:rgb(239, 237, 237);
$google-2:rgb(228, 222, 222);
```

But in reality i have errors like that:

```
Undefined variable.
  ╷
2 │     color:$red-1;
```

I also tried that in another new test project, so this is all not depend on some dependencies.